# International trade routes broken?

Tags: civilization-5

I just get Civilization V BNW I'm trying to use the new international trade routes.

In the description for the route I did just make it says I get 5 gold per turn. So let's say I have 500 gold in first turn, my gold per turn is 0 and my new international trade route says it will generate me +5 gold per turn. My problem is, in turn 2 I still have 500 gold, so I didn't get the +5 my international trade route should give me.

Is international trade routes broken or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6):

**Trade Routes are already factored in to your gold per turn!**

Though this may not be immediately obvious, if you mouse over the Gold / Turn display, you'll get an itemized list of costs and income, one of which will be the sum of all of your trade routes.

Comment: Yes, I did saw that early. My question is, when is the gold incoming from international trade routes given?. If I have 0 gold per turn after making the route then is not given per turn. Is it given at the end of the trade route (when you can select a new one)?

Comment: @Ashir No, you get the gold for every turn the trade route exists.

Comment: Then why still shows 0 gold per turn?. If the route gives 5+ per turn then my treasure should be 5+, right?

Comment: @Ashir No. There are about a hundred different things in the game that either provide or cost gold per turn. In that same turn you created the trade route, you may have finished buildings, which cost maintenance, you may have had a city grow in population, and shuffle around which tiles it was harvesting in response, etc. Without an itemized list of everything affecting your gold per turn rate, it's impossible to know. Fortunately, as Raven Dreamer pointed out, all you have to do is hover over the display, and you get such a list.